# Error when importing scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When trying to import scipy I get the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\INRO\Emme\Emme 4\Emme-4.2.7\python-lib\win64\2.7\modeller\inro.director.application\inro\director\application\run.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 import scipy

C:\Program Files\INRO\Emme\Emme 4\Emme-4.2.7\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>()
     59 __all__ = ['test']
     60
---> 61 from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
     62
     63 from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config

ImportError: No module named _distributor_init
```

I installed numpy and scipy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
By checking `numpy.show_config()` I believe I am indeed using a numpy with Intel MKL.
Using Python 2.7.9 in windows 10 .

Comment: On the page you linked to it says: "Many binaries depend on numpy-1.11+mkl and the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 (x64, x86, and SP1 for CPython 2.6 and 2.7), Visual C++ 2010 (x64, x86, for CPython 3.3 and 3.4), or the Visual C++ 2015 (x64 and x86 for CPython 3.5) redistributable packages.
Install numpy+mkl before other packages that depend on it." Did you explicitly install this package?

Comment: As I said, I installed numpy from the same page where he said me to and I checked using  numpy.show_config() which gave me some stuff with quite a few "MKL", so I guess I did. Do you know any better way of checking it?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you are seeing mkl everywhere then it should be installed. Did you use pip to install Scipy? If so, what version of pip are you using? You can check with: pip --version

Comment: I did use pip using the .whl provided on that site $ ./python -m pip --version gives 
pip 8.1.2 from C:\notRealFolder\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine so I can't test this myself at the moment, but have you tried installing directly from the pip repository, rather than downloading the files from that page? Try uninstalling numpy and scipy, then installing them using: "python -m pip install numpy-mkl" then "python -m pip install scipy".

Answer (score 0):

you can install it handy ...
by that :

you should uninstall your ***numpy*** if you have it
by

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

then you have to install wheel package which help you with handy package installing :

```
pip install wheel
```

then go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/ .. find and download your appropriate package ( something like **numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl** which include **+mkl** and it ends with **.whl**
after the download has completed you can install it with pip

```
pip install "path\name of the file"
```

for example :

```
pip install C:\users\user\downloads\numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

if its failed you have to download the 32bit ones  .... some thing like **numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl**

now you have the **numpy** package with **mkl**
so your **scipy** package works well...
enjoy it

Answer (score -4):

u can import simply by using command prompt...if everything is installed correctly

> import scipy as sp

Comment: I do know how I am supposed to import a package. That was precisely what I did to get the error about which I wrote . So I guess everything is NOT correctly installed, therefore the question is how can fix it.